# Remove prefix tablename in join query result

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Using nodejs(10.15.0),sequelize (4.42.0) and MySQL, am trying the remove table path  from the result in join query.

```
Table1
    .findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'name', 'other'],
      include: [{
        attributes: ['code_id'],
        model: Table2,
        nested: false,
        required: true,
      }],
      raw: true,
    })
```

Query Result

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "stuff",
    "other": true,
    "table2.code_id": 1,
  }
]
```

Expecting to happen

```
      [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "stuff",
    "other": true,
    "code_id": 1,
  }
]
```

Comment: Try adding `as: "code_id"` as a property to the object in the `includes`-array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `raw: true,` - it is preventing Sequelize from parsing the results into objects. If you don't want to use a Model Instance you will need to write your own parser for the results.

Note that it will parse into the following structure ("table2" will be a property):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "stuff",
    "other": true,
    "table2": {
      "code_id": 1,
    }
  }
]
```

Alternatively you could alias the child row, but note that it will go into the `dataValues` only unless you create a VIRTUAL field that maps to it.

```
Table1
.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'id', 'name', 'other',
    [sequelize.col('table2.code_id'), 'code_id'], // aliased here
  ],
  include: [{
    attributes: [],
    model: Table2,
    required: true,
  }],
  raw: true,
})
```

Comment: This is not working as error  "Unknown column 'table2.code' in 'field list" as table2 is not db table name its a model name.

Comment: @NoorFathima I don't have "code" anywhere in my example so I think you have a typo. Maybe you have "code" instead of "code_id"?

Comment: I did exactly how you ask to do,  and I got `SequelizeDatabaseError: The multi-part identifier " ... " could not be bound`.